# CKFinder Zip installation CodeDom Provider Type exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ckfinder

Attempting to install CkFinder as subsite to an ASP.NET MVC web application per ckfinder documentation, via the ZIP download option.  The main MVC site is operating normally, but could not add CKFinder via nuget because of conflicting version information in a required library.

Sandbox test involved adding ckfinder as a subsite to an ASP.NET webforms application, which appeared to work flawlessly right away with only a couple configuration issues.

Now, I added the subsite to one of the "Areas" of the MVC app, and this caused the same exception I will describe in a moment.  Changing the path to the recommended /ckfinder path did not really make a difference.  After installing everything I go to the ckfinder path and get the ugly ASP.NET error page, and if I go to the ckfinder sample page, the ugly error shows up in a popup window.  In Event viewer, this exception is recorded:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. (C:\webs\MainSite\web.config line 369)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. (C:\webs\MainSite\web.config line 369)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_CodeDomProviderType()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.GetCompilerInfoFromExtension(String extension, Boolean throwOnFail)
   at System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetBuildProviderTypeFromExtension(CompilationSection config, String extension, BuildProviderAppliesTo neededFor, Boolean failIfUnknown)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateBuildProvider(VirtualPath virtualPath, BuildProviderAppliesTo neededFor, CompilationSection compConfig, ICollection referencedAssemblies, Boolean failIfUnknown)
   at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.ProcessDirectoryRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
```

The codedom libraries ARE referenced in the web.config file for the main site, but the ckeditor site does not reference them.

So it looks like in the exception it's trying to find the roslyn library from the main site, and as I said ckFinder is installed as a subsite.  The two sites are actually not even installed on the same disk on the server.

** **Update** **

I removed roslyn from the parent application (a separate, standalone solution in ASP.NET 4.6.2, MVC) and now CKFinder works.  However, removing the roslyn/codedom package seems to have broken other features.

Namely I get the new error:

```
Error   CS8026  Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.
```

This error seems odd as Microsoft says I should be running at least C# 7.3 with Visual Studio 2019 and the .NET version 4.6.2.  The project says "latest version" for the C# version in the advanced configuration.

Comment: The statement "Added the subsite to an area of the mvc app" makes no sense. Do you mean you copied it?

Comment: You can substitute area with "subfolder" like domain.com/area/subsitename

Comment: also I don't know what you mean by copied.  the ckfinder comes as a standalone web application in a zip file.  so yes I copied the unzipped files to the location in storage specified in the subsite configuration in IIS.

Comment: How can you say that both "The two sites are actually not even installed on the same disk " and "I added the subsite to one of the "Areas" of the MVC app".

Comment: So "Areas" are apparently a standard feature of an ASP.NET MVC web application.  They are used in my main application for the "admin" section of the site, and also the folder structure of the included web API.  I did not add the ckfinder to the solution, so the subsite exists within the folder structure associated with the "Areas" in IIS.

Comment: Also, Subsites can be configured with their own storage locations on disk.  So I put those storage locations somewhere other than the location of the main site, so that automated deployments do not somehow wipe out ckfinder whenever some other unrelated update is made to the main site.

Comment: As I did try doing this two different ways, one of the subsites I added was at the root level of the main web application and not in some subfolder.   So domain.com/ckfinder and domain.com/areas/path/ckfinder.  This doesn't actually seem to make a difference in whether the roslyn problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the folder with CKFinder is hosted (from IIS perspective) within the folder of your main application, it inherits all the settings from the `web.config` file of the main application.

This includes the setting for the compiler provider. So, because the `web.config` of the main application is applied to the CKFinder project, the compiler provider assembly is searched when the CKFinder project is executed but cannot be found. I see four different approaches:

### 1 Combine into one project

Actually incorporate the CKFinder stuff into your main application so that you have only one Visual Studio web project

### 2 Host as siblings

Host them as siblings on the server and not one within the other (i.e. main application at http://localhost/MainApp/ and CKFinder project at http://localhost/ckfinder/) or using different subdomains.

### 3 Add Compiler to CKFinder app

Open the CKFinder subsite folder in Visual Studio and add the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` Version 2.0.1 nuget package so that the searched assembly compiler provider assembly is also present in the CKFinder app and can be found there.

### 4 Prevent main app from applying compiler options to child apps

Modify the web.config of the main application so that compiler provider settings are not passed on to child applications by embedding the `system.codedom` inside a `location` node:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" ....
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" ....
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</location>
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications

---

If none of this works you should provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did try option 4 but maybe I was too broad in my approach.   3 I didn't think about because it's a precompiled, packaged application.  1 was the very first thing I tried and that won't work because ckfinder uses a different version of some libraries already in the original solution.  2 might have to be the way to go, tbh.

Comment: Sorry, but CKFinder is not a precompiled packaged application. I have just tried to incorporate the Nuget packages into an ASP.net project and it worked flawlessly. As mentioned: Please provide an [mcve] to illustrate your problem

Comment: the nuget package is a separate thing from the zip file download option on the ckfinder website.  The zip file contains a pre-compiled web application.  I will attempt 3 and 4 but like I said I tried the nuget option already and it didn't work due to some of the required libraries being incompatible with my existing project.   You gave me an idea of using the nuget option and running that as its own application either as a subsite or a sibling domain.  I will try these things and let you know.

Comment: I can download the ZIP file, extract it, open the contents in Visual Studio as a website and then add the compiler provider with no problem.

Comment: Option 4 did the job.  I'm not sure what I did differently in my previous attempt.  Maybe I put it in the wrong place or tried to do too much with it.